# JPA generic repository, not working for a certain name

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have made a Jax-RS endpoint, with a JPA integration, where I try to make a query, based on a generic name, to create a query, to get data from the database.

```
@Override public Set<E> get() {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    List<E> results = null;

    try {
        results = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM " + entityClass.getSimpleName() + " e", entityClass)
                    .getResultList();
    } finally {
        em.close();
        return new HashSet<E>(results);
    }
}
```

when I make an instance of my repository, I specify the class name and the primary key in the SQL-database (usually an integer)

```
public class BaseRepository<E, PK> implements CRUDOperations<E, PK> {

    private   Class<E> entityClass;
    protected EntityManagerFactory emf;
}
```

I tried this out for a dummy class, with just a string, in it works fine, 
 I tested it in the debugger.

[image: It gets the right class name and respective data in the database]

[image]

however, when I try to do it for an actual class I created, I just get null back (not even an empty set=

lastly, I checked the database, and the tables have the same name in the database, and that matched.

Comment: I recommend to return your hashset within the try-block, the finally-block will be invoked even after returning it.

Comment: Why would that be prefered?

Comment: because u supress a possible exception which is most likely happening in your code and the reason you get `null`

Comment: makes sense, i will change it

Comment: And how is this related to spring data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that I did not add a no-argument constructor to the entity class, and therefore it failed to fetch a set of entities from the database.